# Watcher condition with inline script containing arithmetic fails

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, lucene

I'm trying to create a watcher that will fire whenever I am using more than 80% of the JVM heap.

I'm making the following query to elasticsearch v7.5.

```
{
    "trigger": {
        "schedule": {
            "interval": "20s"
        }
    },
    "input": {
        "http": {
            "request": {
                "scheme": "https",
                "host": "domain.region.aws",
                "port": 9200,
                "method": "get",
                "path": "/_cluster/stats"
                "params": {},
                "headers": {},
                "auth": {
                    "basic": {
                        "username": "username",
                        "password": "password"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "condition": {
        "script": {
            "inline": "return ((ctx.payload.nodes.jvm.mem.heap_used_in_bytes / ctx.payload.nodes.jvm.mem.heap_max_in_bytes) * 100) > 80"
        }
    },
    "actions": {
        "send_email": {
            "email": {
                "to": "some-email@domain.com",
                "subject": "Watcher Notification",
                "body": "{{ctx.payload.nodes.jvm.mem.heap_used_in_bytes}} of the JVM heap memory is currently being used."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My condition seems to be returning the wrong results.

For example:

If I change my script to be:

`return ((ctx.payload.nodes.jvm.mem.heap_used_in_bytes / ctx.payload.nodes.jvm.mem.heap_max_in_bytes) * 100) < 1`

`heap_used_in_bytes` = 979683712

`heap_max_in_bytes` = 2739011584

Which should result in: 35.767782719 (False)

Results in a response containing (which is incorrect):

```
"condition": {
  "type": "script",
  "status": "success",
  "met": true
}
```

It seems that when I try even simple queries using variables it doesn't work. For example, changing the condition to `return ctx.payload.nodes.jvm.mem.heap_max_in_bytes > 2739011584` results in a strange compilation error:

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"[script_exception] compile error, with { script_stack={ 0=\"... vm.mem.heap_max_in_bytes 2739011584\" & 1=\"                             ^---- HERE\" } & script=\"return ctx.payload.nodes.jvm.mem.heap_max_in_bytes 2739011584\" & lang=\"painless\" }"}
```

Simple comparisons where I don't use variables seem to be working. I am able to print the value of the variables I am accessing in the script in the value of `body` in the `email` action. Can anyone please shed some light on what is going on here? And is there anyway to print the result of this script in the body of the email somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to that error message, this isn't using Groovy, it's using the default ES language which is `painless`

According to the [painless documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-operators-numeric.html#division-operator), integer division will result in an integer, so `979683712 / 2739011584 == 0`

I am no expert, but [I believe](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-casting.html) changing your painless script to:

```
return ((ctx.payload.nodes.jvm.mem.heap_used_in_bytes / (double)ctx.payload.nodes.jvm.mem.heap_max_in_bytes) * 100) < 1
```

Should fix it (as it with cast the denominator of the division into a `double`)

Alternatively, you should be able to do:

```
    "condition": {
        "script": {
            "lang": "groovy",
            "inline": "return ((ctx.payload.nodes.jvm.mem.heap_used_in_bytes / ctx.payload.nodes.jvm.mem.heap_max_in_bytes) * 100) > 80"
        }
    },
```

To use groovy instead...

Hope that helps...  Can't easily test it

Comment: Thanks Tim, this was it..! Changing the painless script as you suggested (casting to a double) has fixed the problem.